# The system cannot find the file specified but works when direct in command line

Tags: c#, command-line

I am struggling to use Chromes print to PDF feature via headless browsing.

My code is very simple

```
var command = "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=\"D:\\GitHub\\MySite\\bin\\Debug\\Temp\\createPdf180303084003.pdf\"   http://localhost/mypage";
Process.Start(command);
```

When I view my `command` and copy the string, and paste that into a command prompt, it works fine.

This is all on one system so I don't understand why it works in command prompt and not in my C# web app.

Comment: How are you invoking this command?

Comment: Updated post @RonBeyer

Comment: You need to separate the process (path to chrome) and the arguments as two different strings passed into `Process.Start`, see [MSDN on Process.Start(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RonBeyer would you please move to an answer

Comment: You can accept one of the existing ones, no point duplicating what is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
proc.Arguments = @"--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=\""D:\\GitHub\\MySite\\bin\\Debug\\Temp\\createPdf180303084003.pdf\""   http://localhost/mypage";
Process.Start(proc);
```

Answer (score 1):

The system is now searching for the file `"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=\"D:\\GitHub\\MySite\\bin\\Debug\\Temp\\createPdf180303084003.pdf\"   http://localhost/mypage"`, but you want it to launch `"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"` with some arguments. What you need to do is:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments";
process.Start();
```